# Characterization of a Subring, shouldnot we concern $ab$ and $ba$ simultaneously?

Tags: group-theory

In my book, "Elements of Modern Algebra, 7th ed.- /Gilberts"

Characterization of a Subring is given as following (that is, conditions to be a subring of a ring $R$)

> A subset $S$ of a ring $R$ is a subring of $R$ if and only if these conditions are satisfied:
>
> - $S$ is not empty
> - $x,y\in S\Rightarrow x-y,xy\in S$

in the second condition if we do not check if $yx$ is in $S$, ***will there be a problem?*** Because I guess there might be a counter-example considered with matrix groups or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We actually check both $xy$ and $yx$ with this axiom, but it isn't that apparent.

Look closely on what's said:

$$\forall x,y \in S \quad x-y\in S, xy \in S$$

See that "for all" symbol? It means that the same should be true if we swap $x$ and $y$! So, if $a,b \in S$, we have

- $ab \in S$, if we take $x=a$ and $y=b$, and
- $ba \in S$, if we take $x=b$ and $y=a$.